# Flatten commits on a branch

Tags: git

Is it possible to condense the commits on a branch into a single commit prior to merging with the main? I thought this would be a fairly common scenario, but maybe I am not using the right search terms.

I'll explain the scenario in more detail. Often I would want to make many local commits while working on a change in a branch to ensure I have a comprehensive history of changes. But once through with the changes in the branch, when I am merging to main, I would like to reduce the commits on the branch to a single one and then merge it to main. I do understand that commits are inexpensive in Git, but in some situations, I might just prefer to do this.

```
*   merge to main
|\
* | commit 2 on main
* | commit 1 on main
| * commit 2 on branch
| * commit 1 on branch
|/
*   branch from main
```

to be made to look like

```
*   merge to main
|\
* | commit 2 on main
* | commit 1 on main
| * commit on branch (branch commits flattened to one)
|/
*   branch from main
```

I'm a novice when it comes to git. If I have erred in the use of terms, I do apologise.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use interactive rebasing. Find the commit where your branch diverged from master (may using `git merge-base`; let's call the commit `<diverge>`), then

```
git rebase -i <diverge>
```

and an editor will pop up, allowing you to rewrite history interactively. You'll want to squash commits.

Comment: Thanks. After looking around for more following your hint, I found this (http://ariejan.net/2011/07/05/git-squash-your-latests-commits-into-one/) post as well that walks through with an example.

Answer (score 34):

I would recommend learning to use the interactive rebase, but in case it seems too complicated to you, you can simply use

`git reset --soft <diverging-commit>`

to undo all commits up to the diverging point without changing the index, and

`git commit -s`

to make a single commit of all the changes.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `git merge --squash <branch>` to merge a branch without performing any commits:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash mybranch
...
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
$ git commit
```

(Update: Removed link to article advocating avoidance of history rewriting. I now think squashing small feature branches prior to review is a good practice.)

Comment: The article about lying seems overly concerned with "lying to make you look good". That's all well and good but how about reorganising commits to make code review simpler for the reviewer, an honourable aim. How bad would lying in this context be?

Answer (score 3):

Look at `git rebase`.  The `-i` option gives you the chance to edit, squash (what you want), or even remove, commits.

For example, the way I use it generally is as:

```
git rebase -i origin/master
....
git push
```